# .htaccess - translation to layman terms needed

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess is running with the Zend framework and one of our developers previously added this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Can someone please translate this to English for me? I believe it is saying, if someone tries to access index.php, then do a 301 redirect to the main domain (i.e. don't show the world "index.php" exists). I don't know why the RewriteCond is there when the RewriteRule has the same rule it seems, perhaps this was a mistake. Anyway I don't know if it even works as there are other rules and my site can actually access the index.php file (no redirection) so perhaps the above can be removed entirely. Looking for a proper translation of this to understand.

Many thanks!

Comment: @rishjid Do either of the answers below help you? Could you mark one of them as accepted?

Comment: @Jon Hi Jon, yes both answers do indeed help me - I wanted to mark them as accepted but I haven't yet officially tried this (as we have had a couple of new tasks to clear before coming back to this). I want to try both and mark the answer that helped me the most as accepted which I will do as soon as I complete this fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually both `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` are required here. But first thing first this rule isn't going to work way it is.

Correct working code will be this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Main difference is presence of `/` in your `RewriteRule` which will fail it for `http://domain.com/index.php`

**Explanation:**

- `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser
- You need to match URI with `THE_REQUEST` to make sure `/index.php` is there in the original URI and not a result of some internal rewrite to `/index.php`
- If you remove `RewriteCond` it might still work but you have to make sure that none of rules are rewriting your URI to `/index.php` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Yes my application does write to index.php - it is a Zend Framework application and almost all requests are forwarded to index.php. The purpose here is that direct requests to the application's index.php file must be handled accordingly. Question - can you check the reply below and confirm if I can go ahead and use your code since your explanation states that I should use RewriteCond given that my application uses index.php for routing? Also, you included (.*?) - I assume the "?" will catch http://domain.com/index.php where there is nothing before index.php?

Comment: Absolutely correct `(.*?)` is called non-greedy quantifier in regex which can match nothing if URL is `http://domain.com/index.php` and it will match `/dir1/` if URL is `http://domain.com/dir1/index.php` Yes sure go ahead and use this rule, but make sure this is your first rule in `.htaccess` otherwise those routing rules grab all the URLs. (I have checked Jon's answer and as I stated it will work as long as there is no routing like rules to `/index.php`)

Answer (score 1):

The `RewriteCond` *[test string](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)* contains the server-variable `%{THE_REQUEST}` which takes the form:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1
or
POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
```

The *condition pattern* `^.*/index.php` contains a regular expression that matches anything with `/index.php` in it...

The `^` marks the start of the string, the `.*` matches zero-or-more instances of *any* character and the `/index.php` is self-explanatory.

So, any URL which contains `/index.php` will be matched. If the *condition pattern* ended with a `$` symbol (the end-of-string symbol), then it wouldn't match any instance of `%{THE_REQUEST}` as all instances of `%{THE_REQUEST}` contain the HTTP request type after the URL.

The `RewriteRule` is then used to do the 301 redirect as you describe, but importantly, the [RewriteRule directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) matches it's *pattern* against the current URL (and not against the whole request string like the RewriteCond does in this example).

The RewriteRule *pattern* `^(.*)/index.php` captures (denoted by the brackets) everything in front of `/index.php` and then creates a 301 redirect that removes the `/index.php`.

@anubhava has pointed out that if you visit `website.com/index.php` then the RewriteRule won't work, because the URL it matches against does not include the leading `/`.

Those two lines can be rewritten as:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Then, if you visit `http://website.com/index.php` then the `(.*)` part of the *pattern* will match an empty string.

Or if you visit `http://website.com/sub/folder/index.php` then the `(.*)` part of the *pattern* will match `sub/folder/`, which is then referenced in the *substitution* string by `$1`.

Remember that every redirect works by telling the browser to request a new URL, and each request gets re-processed by the htaccess, so if there are other rules that allow viewing `index.php` then that could explain why you can see some URLs containing index.php.

Comment: Thank you so much! Both the answers really helped understand and fix the problem. I've used the first answer above but both work very well. Thank you!